# Google App Engine: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, find, classcastexception

I have upgraded my GAE server application with the latest GAE SDK 1.9.17 and it stopped work.
I am facing a problem while performing 'entityManager.find(Profile.class, 'some long value representing profile id')'.

Here is a stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFieldManager.fetchIntField(DatastoreFieldManager.java:435)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingIntField(AbstractStateManager.java:1132)
    at xxx.Profile.jdoReplaceField(Profile.java)
    at xxx.Profile.jdoReplaceFields(Profile.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.replaceFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2772)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.replaceFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2791)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.fetchObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:519)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.validate(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:4263)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2444)
    at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:234)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastoreEntityManager.find(DatastoreEntityManager.java:56)
    at xxx.GameAdd$1.run(GameAdd.java:34)
    at xxx.GameAdd$1.run(GameAdd.java:29)
    at xxx.Action.execute(Action.java:112)
    at xxx.GameAdd.doPost(GameAdd.java:28)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:484)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

The entity I find is look like:

```
@Entity
public class Profile
{
  public Key getKey() {return key;}

  // Other public methods 

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;

  // Other data fields
}
```

The problem started right after I've upgraded the GAE SDK.
Code wasn't changed. I always did searches using 'long' values that represent profile id.

I tried to use `KeyFactory.createKey()` method to generate a key for `find` method but it didn't help either.

Example:

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Profile.class.getSimpleName(), 12345);

Profile p = entitymanager.find(Profile.class, key);
```

I would appreciate any advises since my server application is unavailable and can't serve end users.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which line of code causes this error?

Comment: ferp.center.server.servlet.GameAdd$1.run(GameAdd.java:34) 

This line executes:

entityManager.find(Profile.class, 12345)

Comment: This line `Profile p = entitymanager.find(Profile.class, key);` cannot give you the same error. What do you mean by "did not help either"?

Comment: Unfortunately the same effect. I see exactly the same exception.
Actually, it was just an example '12345'. In the code I pass to the 'createKey' method a long variable. 
I verified it a few times.

Here the exact code lines:
Profile p = em.find(Profile.class, KeyFactory.createKey(Profile.class.getSimpleName(), input.profile));

Where input object is:
public class RequestGameResult
{
  public long profile;

  //... other data fields 
}

Comment: I use IntelliJ Ultimate 14.0.2 which never did any problem, but maybe you'll find this information useful.

Comment: I noticed that I receive another error when I try to persist a Profile entity object:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: out of field index :9
 at xxx.Profile.jdoCopyField(Profile.java)
 at xxx.Profile.jdoCopyFields(Profile.java)
 ...

I think there is a connection between two problems.
Could it be related some how to JPA entity enhancement process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a chance of a problem in your build environment, especially if you have just upgraded to the new version and everything did work before. Try to use another tool to build the application, e.g. ant. You can find directions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/ant). It is fairly easy and quick to make it work and it should give you an indication whether the problem is indeed in the new IntelliJ GAE support.

Comment: Many thanks - you saved my day!
These instructions indeed resolved my problem and I was managed to upload new version of my server to GAE using 'ant'.
Obviously there is a problem with IntelliJ 14.0.2.
Hopefully JetBrain will fix it in next release.

Answer (score 0):

Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Profile.class.getSimpleName(), 12345);

12345 is considered an Int...

Try this:

long longVal = 12345;

Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Profile.class.getSimpleName(), longVal);

===---===

Let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately the same effect. I see exactly the same exception. Actually, it was just an example '12345'. In the code I pass to the 'createKey' method a long variable. I verified it a few times. Here the exact code lines: Profile p = em.find(Profile.class, KeyFactory.createKey(Profile.class.getSimpleName(), input.profile)); Where input object is: public class RequestGameResult { public long profile; //... other data fields }

I use IntelliJ Ultimate 14.0.2 which never did any problem, but maybe you'll find this information useful.

Comment: I noticed that I receive another error when I try to persist a Profile entity object:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: out of field index :9
 at xxx.Profile.jdoCopyField(Profile.java)
 at xxx.Profile.jdoCopyFields(Profile.java)
 ...

I think there is a connection between two problems.
Could it be related some how to JPA entity enhancement process?